# Dynamic solution to group by an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to do a group by over an array of objects. The array that I'm trying to group by is subject to change and I need a solution that's dynamic.

This is how the array that i'm trying to work on looks like.

```
const arr = [
  {
      first: {
          label: 'a',
          key: 'a'
      },
      second: {
          label: 'b',
          key: 'b',
      }
  },
  {
      first: {
          label: 'aa',
          key: 'aa'
      },
      second: {
          label: 'bb',
          key: 'bb',
      }
  }
]
```

I've tried this so far:

```
const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc['first'] = acc['first'] || [];
  acc['second'] = acc['second'] || [];
  acc['first'].push(curr.first);
  acc['second'].push(curr.second);

  return acc;
}, {});
```

This solves my problem, but it's not a dynamic solution.

This is the expected result:

```
const obj = {
  first: [
      {
          label: 'a',
          key: 'a'
      },
      {
          label: 'aa',
          key: 'aa'
      }
  ],
  second: [
      {
          label: 'b',
          key: 'b'
      },
      {
          label: 'bb',
          key: 'bb'
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this more general, you simply need to loop over the keys, rather than hardcoding your `first`/`second` code. That should look something like this:

```js
const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let keys = Object.keys(curr);
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
    acc[key].push(curr[key]);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and `Object.entries`

```js
const arr = [{first: {label: 'a',key: 'a'},second: {label: 'b',key: 'b',}},{first: {label: 'aa',key: 'aa'},second: {label: 'bb',key: 'bb',}}]

let final = arr.reduce((op, inp) => {
  Object.entries(inp).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    op[key] = op[key] || []
    op[key].push(value)
  })
  return op
},{})

console.log(final)
```